# How to check if a regex capturing group is empty

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have following regex capturing group (?'my_group'[ \w.\&-/]*) which matches a text with specified characters. My regular expression also matches an empty line with only one whitespace in it.  `'my_group'` is empty in that case, but it does exist.

Now, depending on whether `my_group` is empty or not, I would like to go on to the next match or to match the next line too.

I've tried to use conditional `(?('my_group')<regex to match next line>|<skip>)`, but the condition always evaluates to true, even when `my_group` is empty.

How could I solve that?

Comment: What language are you using?  There may be something specific/clever depending on which one e.g. python, ruby, etc.

Comment: @sniperd I've started with regex101, pcre(php)-flavour: https://regex101.com/r/kLGkMW/4
My problem are the lines starting with 1 and 3, which don't get matched